# Reactjs: Invariant Violation: You may not have more than one route named "universal-search"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I need to have the same sub-route in 2 different routes

```
<Route name="app" path="/" handler={App}>
  <Route name="management" path="management" handler={Management}>
    <Route name="universal-search" path="universal-search" handler={UniversalSearch} />
    <Route name="game-info" path="game-info" handler={GameInfo} />
    <DefaultRoute handler={UniversalSearch} />
  </Route>
  <Route name="operations" path="operations" handler={Operations}>
    <Route name="universal-search" path="universal-search" handler={UniversalSearch} />
    <Route name="videos" path="videos" handler={Videos} />
    <DefaultRoute handler={UniversalSearch} />
  </Route>

  <DefaultRoute handler={UniversalSearch} />      
</Route>

<Route name="login" handler={Login} />
```

the route I need is this one

`<Route name="universal-search" path="universal-search" handler={UniversalSearch} />`

But I am getting the error in the question

> Invariant Violation: You may not have more than one route named "universal-search"

I need to move among routes, and persist that route, what should I do ?

Comment: is your default route supposed to be the one under `management` or the one under `operations`?

Comment: yes, @Claies I mean, that should be the default route in every view/route

Comment: @Claies sorry, I did not get it, but look, management is one parent route and operations is another one, if you go to one or the other, the menu changes, but I need to persist universal-search on both: management and operations.

Comment: Did you try to rename your sub-default routes like : name="management-universal-search" and "operations-universal-search"?